# React Reflux error when running compiled JSX but not when using transformer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

When I include my JSX code directly in a script tag

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="jsx/components.jsx"></script>
```

my react program loads and works properly, but if I compile my JSX to a javascript file and include it

```
<script src="js/components.js"></script>
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: listenable is undefined
>   http://localhost/js/reflux.js
>   Line 669

I'm compiling with the following command

```
jsx -x jsx/ js/
```

Is there something special that needs to be done to pre-compile JSX when using Reflux?

Comment: Are you able to find the problematic in your code, not the reflux code. You should probably look for a typo like listenable instead of listenables.

Comment: I have not found a problem in my code (not to say that there isn't one though).  As for "listenable", that is coming from the reflux.js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution to this.  It was a problem with my code, although a subtle one.
In my index.html, I had the scripts loading in the following order:

```
components.js
actions.js
store.js
```

Moving the components to last fixed the error.

```
actions.js
store.js
components.js
```